# Parsley.JS not working in Meteor (anymore)

Tags: meteor, parsley.js

I Updated to the latest meteor version and I'm also running the latest `parsley.js` version my validation has stopped working it seems that

```
$('#create-post').parsley().options.trigger = 'change';
$('#create-post').parsley().reset();
```

Is not firing in meteor (on render template) but works fine in JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/grbcwa9b/

Really not sure why it's not working anymore has anyone else run into this issues

Comment: None why it's hard to really debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get to the bottom of this I had create post id twice once in my navigation and once in form this was causing the conflict

```
<li class="{{isActiveRoute regex='create-post'}}">
<a href="{{pathFor 'create-post'}}" id="create-post"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i><span class="title">{{mf 'create-post' 'Create Post'}}</span></a>
</li>
```